# When should I flag a comment as obsolete (and when to use a custom flag instead)?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

Based on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209551/what-do-mods-see-when-reviewing-my-comment-flag) moderators see all flagged comments in isolation and don't usually go to the post to investigate further.

In terms of flagging as obsolete, reasons include:

- The post has been edited to include or address the comment.
- It's a reply to a deleted comment and doesn't mean anything on its own.
- Perhaps something about the homework tag ... or similar.
- Perhaps something about an obsolete technology or similar, which a moderator shouldn't be expected to be able to judge anyway.
- Umm... (just about everything else I can think of at this very moment would classify as "too chatty")

When the post has been edited, if the editor didn't reply saying that the post has been edited (or if you're the editor), would a simple obsolete flag do here? Would the moderator go check it out or just delete the comment without doing so?

Similarly in the case of a reply to a deleted comment.

Should I use a custom flag instead saying `"The post has been edited to include this information"`, or `"This is a reply to a deleted comment and doesn't mean anything on its own"`? If so, wouldn't this largely render the "obsolete" flag ... well, obsolete.

Are there any other reasons to use the "obsolete" flag?

Comment: In my experience, I've had no problems flagging these comments as "obsolete".

Comment: I've actually had this thought too; the only time I've had a comment flag denied is in that second reason (reply to deleted comment). Would be good to know that I don't have to be super paranoid about comment flags.